# Landing Page post to itself and run SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page

i found a great blog post by Adam Spriggs 
https://sprignaturemoves.com/prune-rows-data-extension-ssjs/

He mentioned to execute this function be built a landing page that posts to itself and calls the function.

This might be a very basic question but can someone tell me what this landing page would look like. I have tried some basic form submit but i continually get function undefined which i believe is because i am wanting to execute servcer side script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways this might work. Here are a couple of examples...

**AMPScript**

```
%%[ IF @@ExecCtx == "LOAD" THEN]%%
    <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%"> method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
%%[ ELSEIF @@ExecCtx == "POST" THEN]%%
    %%[/*Handle post here*/]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

**Server Side JavaScript**

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    if (Request.Method == "GET") {
</script>
    <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%"> method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    }
    else if (Request.Method == "POST") {
        // Handle post
        Write(Stringify(Request));
    }
</script>
```

I tend to assume I'm working with SSJS for Landing Pages, but it's a question of personal preferences for the most part.