# how to create a landing page that posts to itself and calls a SSJS function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to implement the prunerows() ssjs function that Adam Spriggs specifies on this link,
https://sprignaturemoves.com/prune-rows-data-extension-ssjs/

But i am not sure how to create a landing page to post to itself and then call this SSJS function. Can someone please explicitly specify what kind of SSJS code that i will need to have in the landing page to use the prunerows() function

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can refer to this link here, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176675/landing-page-post-to-itself-and-run-ssjs

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176675/landing-page-post-to-itself-and-run-ssjs , You can refer here

Comment: @Kumar, thanks for your help. I am getting an error message "{"GetHeader":"function","GetQueryStringParameter":"function","GetFormField":"function","ApplicationID":null,"PackageID":null,"ApplicationBaseURL":null,"PagePath":null,"Method":"POST","IsAuthenticated":false,"URL":"function"}"

Comment: @Kumar, do you know why? I just copy pasted the prunerows function into the code after where it says " else if (Request.Method == "POST") {
        // Handle post"

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific ? Where are you using your prunerows function and also the self posting landing page ? And your use case, so it is easy to give a better solution.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have actually figured out a better way to implement this. Since I was trying to delete like 100,000 records, i have found it is better to run the prunerows function in a script activity instead of a landing page.

Comment: Sure, I could be of your help. So, did you loop through for retrieving 100,000 records? What was the script activity time to complete deletion? Share your code, so it can help other's. Thank you